# Saving passwords in a separate file

Tags: python

I'm trying to save my passwords to a separate `.py`  file and import them into an API login script.

I just want something simple, have tried (Password file) `details.py`

```
username = "MyUser"
password = "Pass123"
appKey = "123Key"
```

and then imported to my script:

```
import betfairlightweight
from .details import username, password, appKey
```

Error message:

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

```
trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(username, password, app_key=appKey)
trading.login_interactive()
```

Why am I receiving this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Using an SQL database would be much easier in the long term. Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: I just want something quick and simple at the moment @el-banto - This is my first day using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common mistake in Python to confuse the dot in a import path as the dot in the folder system. In Python, the dot refers to the current package, while in the folder system it refers to the current folder. Basically a package in Python is defined as a folder with a `__init__.py` file.

So here when you enter `from .details import username`, what Python does is it tries to import `username` from the module `details` in the current package. If the current folder has a `__init__.py` file, no problem, but I don't think it's your case, hence the error.

What you want to write here is : `from details import username, password, appKey`.

You should see [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) post to understand more about relative imports.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is a very clear an informative answer Bastien. You are correct, the folder has `no __init__.py file`  I removed the `.` but am now receiving a `ModuleNotFoundError` `No module named 'details'`

Comment: Hum... Are you sure the name is right? Like `detail`` instead of `details`? Are you sure `details.py` is in the same folder as your "main" file?